# Work in Small Field or Resize?

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to make small figures (9.4mm height) to print (resin) and place on my model sailboats.  Is it better to design characters in a meter field and resize it down to millimeters, or would it be better to design the characters in a millimeter field?  I ask because I run into issues (belnder freezes) when I remesh even the simplest cube in the millimeter field.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be entering a different unit and pretending it's another one to just scale it later - there is no need for that. It's best to work in real units. If you work with small scale you can change the unit size in Scene tab of the Properties editor, Units panel:

[image]

This will consider 1 unit in Blender scene internally to represent 1mm instead of default 1m:

[image]

This might help avoid precision issues and help with some stuff in Blender like for example there is a limit to how much you can zoom in in Blender, so scaling unit size will solve any issues with that. Setting up correct units for your purpose is convenient, because you then can just enter numbers as the units you work with numerically so for example instead of 0.007 it's just 7. That's less typing in many cases. All Blender input fields representing values that have units(well, at least it's supposed to be all... [disappointed glance at Bump shader node]) and [modal operator advanced numeric input mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/precision/numeric_input.html#advanced-mode) support converting units on the fly so that's also convenient if you work in millimeters for example, but have some measurement in inches you can just enter it followed by "in" and it will be converted for you.

Comment: thank you for that!   I appreciate your info.